# How do Hazelcast-wm nodes find each other in P2P mode?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters, hazelcast

[The docs](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-wm) state that Hazelcast-wm runs in P2P mode by default and the nodes will find each other with no configuration necessary. Does this require all nodes to be running on the same physical server? It's not clear to me how the nodes would find each other if they're running on physically separate servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JCN since all nodes are Hazelcast members in P2P mode, they discover each other. By default, Hazelcast uses multicast for member doscovery so if multicast is open in the network, nodes finds each other & form a cluster even if they’re in the separate machines. Please see related section in the Hazelcast documentation: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#discovery-mechanisms